# What exactly is a pure function when we are talking about a function within a function

Tags: functional-programming, purely-functional, pure-function

I've learned that a pure function is a function that doesn't alter global state, period. If this is true, functions within functions can alter the state of the outer function and still be pure, correct?

Example:

```
function func1() {
  let name = "My Name"
  func2()  

  function func2() {
    // alter name here.
  }
}
```

In the above example, `func2` is still pure because it doesn't use any global state.

That's how I see, but my working colleagues believe that `func2` is not pure, and it should be writen like:

```
function func1() {
  let name = "My Name"
  func2(name)  

  function func2(name) {
    // use name here.
  }
}
```

Which is bad, because:

- if the v8 doesn't optimize this, the CPU will run more instructions
- shadowing is a bad practice

The question is: What exactly is a pure function when we are talking about a function within a function?

Comment: use != alter. Which one are you talking about?

Comment: @Bergi I would like to know your thoughts about both things.

Answer (score 4):

A [pure function](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/what-is-a-pure-function-in-javascript-acb887375dfe) is a function that meets 2 requirements:

1. Given the same input, it will always return the same output.
2. Produces no side effects.

[Side effects](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-functional-programming-7f218c68b3a0) can be defined as **'any application state change that is observable outside the called function other than its return value'**.

To be more specific:

- A function that modifies anything outside it's scope (even if it's not the global scope) is not a pure function.
- In your example, if func2 modifies a variable outside its own scope, then it's not a pure function:

```
function func1() {
  let name = "My Name"; // <-- the variable is not in the global scope but, in any case, it is outside the scope of func2
  func2();

  function func2() {
    // alter name here.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Purity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) is not defined to care only about global variables, it cares about any *non-local* variables (and more) that shouldn't be mutated. An outer variable of a closure still counts as non-local, it doesn't need to be global.

So if `func2` changes `name`, then it's impure. Whether `func1` becomes impure as well through that depends on whether you consider only external purity - as long as `name` and `func2` stay local within the function, it may still be pure.

Answer (score 1):

> I've learned that a pure function is a function that doesn't alter global state, period.

Well, that's oversimplifying. A pure function should one, not have side effects, and two, its outcome should rely only on the arguments. So, as a corollary, no state. Your `func1`'s `name` property suspiciously look like a state. Could I mutate it? Will `func1()` yield different results dependent of the previous calls? Impure!

Of course, func2 being impure is beyond dispute. You wrote "alters name" - 'name' is outside its scope. It's a side effect.

Answer (score 0):

Another example I think it's worth mentioning is the follow **pure function**:

```
function insert(DB, user) {
    return function() {
        throwIfUserExists(DB, user);
        var savedUser = saveUser(DB, user);
        return savedUser;
    }
}
```

Note, that when you call `insert`, as long as you keep sending in the same `DB` and `user`, you will receive the same output as the function returns another function - no side effect happens.